# delegate from a objc to swift to dismiss modal view

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I have a objc uiviewcontroller that perform a segue to a swift uiviewcontroller in modal. I create the delegate in the objc file, but i can't call the method in objc from the swift file. All the files seams to be ok, but when calling delegate.function gives me a bad exec in the swift file.

**objc**

```
 #import "Cliente-Swift.h"
 @interface ViewController () <gameDelegate>
 @end

  (...)

   else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToGame"]) {
        //jump to main vgame controller
        GameViewController *gameVC =  [segue destinationViewController];
        gameVC.mydelegate = self;
    }
```

**swift `GameViewController`**

```
@objc protocol gameDelegate {
   func dismissGame()
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var mydelegate: gameDelegate! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = MainMenuScene(size:CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))
    //let scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))

    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.showsPhysics = true;
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}


override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}


func sairDoJogo() {

    print("mydelegate = \(mydelegate!)")


    mydelegate!.dismissGame()
```

the bad exec is where in the call to the objc function dismissGame

Comment: Where you are assigning self to your delegate? self.mydelegate = self

Comment: in the prepareForSegue gameVC.mydelegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect, that `mydelegate` is not really set.
You should check whether `mydelegate` is really set in `prepareForSegue:...` maybe by adding a log output: (Is your segue id correct?)

```
else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToGame"]) {
    //jump to main vgame controller
    NSLog(@"Setting game delegate");
    GameViewController *gameVC =  [segue destinationViewController];
    gameVC.mydelegate = self;
}
```

In `GameViewController` you may either check whether or not `mydelegate` is `nil` before the call to `dismissGame()`, or just use `?`: (As you declare `mydelegate` as `gameDelegate!`, the `!` in your call is not necessary, as it is "implicitly there" - but you can still use `mydelegate?.dismissGame()`)

```
    if mydelegate != nil {
        mydelegate.dismissGame()
    }
```

or

```
    mydelegate?.dismissGame()
```

(I made a quick test with a sample project and having `mydelegate` not initialized leads to the errors you described.)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. I got it. Theres nothing about delegation, or objc and swift integration. The delegate are fine and all the rest too. The problem is how i'm calling back the uiviewcontroller from the spritekit scene, as soon as i realize that I solve the problem. Thanks again